# How can I enable different services for different users?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-services

How can I disable/enable specific services from starting up on windows load for specific users on my PC?

#### Practical example:

1. UserA, the developer, needs to have all the services available at windows start (SQL Server, Xampp etc.);
2. UserB, the gamer, does not need any of the database services to start for his logon.

If I use the `msconfig` utility it is applied to all the users.

Comment: In services, double click the service you wish to restrict, go to the "log on" tab and select "this account" radio button and allow the account you wish to use the particular service.

Comment: That won't do, Moab; that'll only run the service with the given credentials, not control when it does and doesn't run. See my answer below for the best option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; Windows services start at boot, not at logon. Your best option here would I think be to set the services in question to manual start, then use Group Policy Editor to define logon/logoff scripts for each user, using "net start" commands at logon and "net stop" commands at logoff to start and stop the various services a given user needs. Won't work well if more than one user is logged on at a time, but probably the best way to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: Thanks. Its pretty much of a long shot but I think it is the best available option other than dual boot.

Answer (score -1):

That is easy.

1. Press Windows key + R. The run dilogue box will open.
2. Type msconfig and then click on startup.
3. Here you can disable and see all the services currently available on your PC.
   You can refer the article in the link for more information -- [Windows 7 Services You Need to Get Rid Of And Their Use](http://techspooler.com/windows-7-services-you-need-to-get-rid-of-and-their-use.html)

Comment: Please read my question in last.